# Trying to parse json for public git repos in swift but receiving "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."

Tags: json, swift, git, parsing

My json looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "sensei",
    "owner": {
        "login": "linkedin",
    },
    "description": "distributed realtime searchable database",
    "fork": false,
},
{
    "name": "linkedin-utils",
    "owner": {
        "login": "linkedin",
    },
    "description": "Base utilities shared by all linkedin open source projects",
    "fork": false,
}
]
```

The structs I built are the following:

```
    struct LinkedinData: Codable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
        var owner: OwnerLogin
        var fork: Bool
    }



  struct OwnerLogin: Codable {
        var login: String
    }
```

My code for parsing is this one:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var linkedinData = [LinkedinData]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urString : String = "https://api.github.com/orgs/linkedin/repos"

                if let url = URL(string: urString) {
                    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                            return //exit out of function
                        }
                        parseJSON(json: data!)

                    }
                    task.resume()
                }

            func parseJSON(json: Data) {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(LinkedinData.self, from: json) {
                    linkedinData = [decodedData]

                }
            }

        }
```

I tried for hours bút it seems impossible to parse the json and retreive the data I am looking for (name, description, owner.login and fork) in a collection type. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decode an array of `LinkedinData`, instead of just one, because your JSON has an array as its root:

```
[ <------- this "[" indicates an array
{
    "name": "sensei",
    "owner": {
        "login": "linkedin",
    },
```

Therefore, you should write:

```
if let decodedData = try? decoder.decode([LinkedinData].self, from: json) {
    linkedinData = decodedData

}
```

Comment: thank you! I changed accordingly and now it is working. my variable linkedinData however does not seem to update the value of its array outside of the function. What can I do?

Comment: You are likely checking it’s value before it is fetched. Remember that fetching stuff online takes time. It will have an updated value in the completion handler (after the `data, response, error) in` bit), so you should do everything that requires the value there. @ALeknud

Answer (score 1):

```
if let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(LinkedinData.self, from: json) {
     linkedinData = [decodedData]
}
```

replace this with

```
 if let decodedData = try? decoder.decode([LinkedinData].self, from: json) {
     linkedinData = decodedData
 }
```

as your topmost object in JSON is an Array.